# Solving $f-cf''=g$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $f-cf''=g$ for $f$ where $g$ is continuous with decay at infinity. They're both functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $c>0$. I used to know how to do this but I've long forgotten.

Comment: This is a standard second order ordinary differential equation. TO solve this I believe you need some information about $g$. The fact that $g$ is continuous and decays at infinity suggests that you are looking at a unique solution under initial conditions

Comment: The domain of the functions is $\mathbb{R}$ and they both decay at infinity.

Answer (score 2):

First we find the Green Function (or Green's Function if one prefers) as

$$G_{xx}(x,x')-\frac1c G(x,x')=0\,\,\text{for}\,\,x\ne x'$$

For $x<x'$, $G(x,x')=A^- e^{(x-x')/\sqrt{c}}$ and for $x>x'$,$g(x,x')=A^+ e^{-(x-x')/\sqrt{c}}$.  Enforcing continuity at $x=x'$ reveals $A^+=A^-=A$.

We also have the condition $G_x(x'^+,x')-G_x(x'^-,x')=-\frac1c$.  Enforcing this condition reveal that $A=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$ and we find that

$$G(x,x')=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}e^{-|x-x'|/\sqrt{c}}$$

Finally, we have the solution to the problem of interest

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(x,x')g(x')\,dx'$$

---

**NOTE:**

We assumed tacitly that $f$ decays to zero as $x\to \pm \infty$. As such, homogeneous solutions must have zero coefficients since otherwise this behavior at infinity would be violated.

Comment: What about the solution of the homogeneous?

Comment: @icv Neither homogeneous solution is bounded on the entire real line.  Therefore, their coefficients are zero.

Comment: 1) the OP specified that $g$ is bounded. This does not need to apply on $f$ 2) any solution make sense for $x\in [x_0, \infty)$ where $x_0$ is the initial point so one solution of the homogeneous is bounded there 3) you may want to mention it anyway

Comment: @icv  In a comment, the OP remarked that both $f$ and $g$ decay at infinity.  Sooo ... I added a note under your suggestion and am responding accordingly. I appreciate your comment and have awarded the comments with +1. ;-)) - Mark